# gdal package is installed in conda environment: but can't be imported in python

Tags: miniconda

I installed the gdal package in gempy miniconda environment using conda install gdal. Later when I tried to import it in python 3.10 installed in conda environment, it showed ModuleNotFound error.

```
`(base) C:\Users\prabe>conda activate gempy
(gempy) C:\Users\prabe>python

(gempy) C:\Users\prabe>conda list gdal
# packages in environment at C:\Users\prabe\miniconda3\envs\gempy:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
gdal                      3.6.2           py310h3565590_3
libgdal                   3.6.2                hd879e17_3

(gempy) C:\Users\prabe>where python
C:\Users\prabe\miniconda3\envs\gempy\python.exe
C:\Users\prabe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(gempy) C:\Users\prabe>where python3
C:\Users\prabe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe

(gempy) C:\Users\prabe>python
Python 3.10.0 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 10 2021, 13:20:59) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'

>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\prabe\\miniconda3\\envs\\gempy\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
>>>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to import gdal and other modules after version 3.1 is to use the following:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo import gdal_array
from osgeo import gdalconst
```

See [documentation here](https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html#usage)  for more information.